# How do I take multiple inputs in different lines in Python so that inputs can be accessed later?

Tags: python

[I want to take input in similar pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xDpf.jpg)
I want user to give inputs in multiple lines and value of multiple lines is provided.(5 in given pic)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Don't use a picture, paste the text. Describe clearly what you want, and what you expect the computer to do. Paste in any code that you have already written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the first line and convert it to an integer. That will tell you how many more lines to read from the user. Then read that many lines.

```
n_lines = int(input('How many lines do you want to input?'))
lines = []
for i in range(n_lines):
    lines.append(input())
```

The for loop could be written more concisely as a list comprehension:

```
n_lines = int(input('How many lines do you want to input?'))
lines = [input() for i in range(n_lines)]
```

N.B use `input()` for Python 3. If you are using Python 2 use `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: THANKS ,the second code worked for me as don't want to use append function.

Answer (score 0):

Who determines how many inputs the program accepts?  You, or the user?  If you, then a loop will work fine.  If the user, you'll have to ask for the number first, then use that in the loop.  Here is what I'm thinking:

```
num_inputs = raw_input("How many lines of data will you enter? ")
data_list = []
for _ in range(num_inputs):
    user_input = raw_input("Please enter a line of data: ")
    data_list.append(user_input)
for item in data_list:
    print item
```

You may want to expand upon this and add some input validation to both the `num_inputs` and `user_input` variables, but I hope this gets the idea across.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use append function.No problem I got the answer thanks .